# Ошибка в cmd при установке qt5reactor через pip

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5, cmd

Хочу начать работать с QT на python (PyQT), до этого в cmd через pip установил PyQT5, и так же к нему мне нужно установить qt5reactor, ввожу pip install qt5reactor, но выдает следующую ошибку

```
C:\Users\User>pip install qt5reactor
Collecting qt5reactor
  Using cached qt5reactor-0.6-py3-none-any.whl (9.1 kB)
Collecting twisted
  Using cached Twisted-19.10.0.tar.bz2 (3.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface>=4.4.2 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from twisted->qt5reactor) (4.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: constantly>=15.1 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from twisted->qt5reactor) (15.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: incremental>=16.10.1 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from twisted->qt5reactor) (17.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Automat>=0.3.0 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from twisted->qt5reactor) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: hyperlink>=17.1.1 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from twisted->qt5reactor) (19.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyHamcrest>=1.9.0 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from twisted->qt5reactor) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from twisted->qt5reactor) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from zope.interface>=4.4.2->twisted->qt5reactor) (45.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from Automat>=0.3.0->twisted->qt5reactor) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.5 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from hyperlink>=17.1.1->twisted->qt5reactor) (2.8)
Building wheels for collected packages: twisted
  Building wheel for twisted (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\TrueGaymer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-71047nu6\\twisted\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-71047nu6\\twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-h2y0nvht'
       cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-71047nu6\twisted\
  Complete output (958 lines):
```

Также в конце вот такая доп. ошибка

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\python\include -Ic:\python\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" /Tcsrc/twisted/test/raiser.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj
    raiser.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\python\libs /LIBPATH:c:\python\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86" /EXPORT:PyInit_raiser build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.8\twisted\test\raiser.cp38-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src/twisted/test\raiser.cp38-win32.lib
       Creating library build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src/twisted/test\raiser.cp38-win32.lib and object build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src/twisted/test\raiser.cp38-win32.exp
    Generating code
    Finished generating code
    LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1158
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-71047nu6\\twisted\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-71047nu6\\twisted\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-y0z78flc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python\Include\twisted' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: попробуйте сначала установить `pip install Twisted`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372706/visual-studio-cant-build-due-to-rc-exe?newreg=f00ac10c2a4448ceb438f258e5c229a4 вот ссылка на решение проблемы